# more install problems

Tags: partitioning, files, root

alright so got through the entire process of installing Ubuntu I thought.
I even got on it and was working on it all day yesterday.
today I restarted my computer to make sure I could still get on. and I cant. the computer starts and asks me which program to boot. it list unetbootin and windows seven.
I chose unetbootin asks me to install Ubuntu again. so I start the installation process. now im stuck on a menu that I will post a picture of on my phone shortly. I don't understand what to do here. im almost ready to give up.
please help.

Comment: is the ubuntu usb still plugged in?

Comment: I was never able to get it to boot from the usb because I could not get in my bios so I just put it directly onto the hard drive. that seemed to work fine the first time.

Comment: Ahh i think that is the problem. try burning to a DVD?

Comment: no can do. I cant get in the bios no matter how many times i try.

Comment: What laptop make and model?

Comment: Toshiba satellite

Comment: What key are you using to get to bios?

Comment: well damn now I hit quit on the portioning menu and it closed out and I am on the Ubuntu desktop again. is it just going to do this everytime i have to restart my computer?

Comment: it was supposed to be f2

Comment: Try the escape key

Comment: at first when i would press it it would work and take me to the boot settings menu. but after 10 times of trying to get it to boot from a cd that i didn't prepare correctly and has ceased allowing me to enter the bios. it just stays on the same screen and eventually shuts off.                                                                                                                                                                                                         escape key does not work either

Comment: Hmm what about F12?

Comment: tried it. tried all buttons

Comment: You might try resetting BIOS & see if the keys work then - How, depends on model I think, [here's one way](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/bios-reset-on-toshiba-satellite)

Answer (score 0):

If the BIOS does not allow you to boot from USB or DVD use the following methods:

A. Upgrade your BIOS (refer to your manufacturer's web site for more information)

OR

B. Hardware solution:

1. remove the hard drive from the laptop, put it in an external enclosure
2. Boot from DVD/USB on another machine and install on the (now external) HDD
3. move the external HDD back into your laptop.

**Note:**

What you're trying to do is possible, but complicated: extract the ISO file into a separate partition, make that partition bootable, boot from that partition, install on another partition, remove the ISO partition.

*However* you already have to have a `grub` installed on your hard drive and manually edit `grub.conf` all through the process above. (Which is something even I wouldn't do: too complex, too much work, too many things can go wrong)

Comment: YEAH THAT DOESNT SOUND WORTH THE TROUBLE